Jshell unable to locate a file that it has
I have a jshell in Vscode that opens multiple files which are important for each other , I have the snowflakefractal which extends fractal , when do /open it opens everything fine no errors , but when I do snowflakefractal.class it says the class I not found , for that matter any class that I have which extends fractal says class not found , but when do /list it gives my snowflakefractal as a class which was opened , but it cannot find my class when I ask It to create new instance
jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.12
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> /open Point.java

jshell> /open Line.java

jshell> /open Polygon.java

jshell> /open Rectangle.java

jshell> /open Square.java

jshell> /open Fractal.java

jshell> /open SnowFlakeFractal.java

jshell> /open DrawingPad.java

jshell> SnowFlakeFractal.class
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   class SnowFlakeFractal
|  SnowFlakeFractal.class
|  ^--------------^

jshell> Rectangle.class
$14 ==> class Rectangle

jshell> Fractal.class
$15 ==> class Fractal

/list

          

Tries restarting jshell , tries restarting computer , my computer blue screened , restarted vsCode , used cmd , use java to make the class file , all of these solutions did not work
/list gives the list of class and SnowFlake is there , but it prints all the code also I dont want that here.

"gives the list of class and SnowFlake is there" -- You say SnowFlake is listed out, but what about SnowFlakeFractal?

Does SnowFlakeFractal.java contain the source code of a class named SnowFlakeFractal?

Yes SnowFlakeFractal is there and SnowFlakeFractal.java does give me my source code

Where does SnowFlake come from?
